# How To Add Custom Notices to Page Top in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, widgets, messages

I'm just started Magento and recently have some issues. So, this is what I want to do: I want to display Notices at the top of the site as following Image.

*Eg:* I want to show **some Discount Coupons on the Top of the site**, I want to **add that message in backend side** and the it will show the customers.

[image]

Comment: Did you get my answer?

Comment: @PrincePatel yes. but didn't clear "Now create static block from admin which contain your discount message. and call block in notices.phtml file to show your discount notice at top of the site" part. could u explain it ?

Comment: Create static block from admin content->block->add new block and enter your discount message in static block. Then call this new static block in notice.phtml with block identifier.

Comment: @PrincePatel. where to use following code ?

<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>

Comment: i did but. it works without that code. why should it add to notice.phtml ?

Comment: I write 2 methods, First one for widget and second one for files

Comment: done thanks. how do i style it ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## **Method 1:**

Create new widget by

1. go to CONTENT > Widgets and add widget
2. Choose your theme and type: **CMS Static Block**
3. In layout updates

**Display on: All Pages**

**Container: Page Top**

[image]

5. In Widget Options select your static block which contain your discount message

## **Method 2:**

Override **notices.phtml** in your theme.

**From**

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/notices.phtml

**To your theme**

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/notices.phtml

Now create static block from admin and enter your discount message. Then call this static block in **notices.phtml** file to show your discount notice at top of the site

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: Ha..ha.. Yeah! Okay! Never mind!

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, we can use Widget: **CONTENT > Widgets**. Choose CMS static Block type. In the **Layout Updates**. Choose Page Top container (need to test again, not test yet):
[image]

Comment: How this can be done pro-grammatically? any suggesions

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to do this is using Magento build in widgets. Please follow the given instructions:

1. Create a new static block in admin that will contain your coupon code HTML.
2. Create a new widget as follow:

   Content >> Widgets >> Click "Add widget" Button.

From the widget form, select the following:

**StoreFront Properties Tab**

```
Type => CMS static block

Design Theme => Your custom theme (Press continue button)

Widget Title => Widget Name

Assign to Store Views => All
```

**Layout Updates Section:**

```
Display On => All Pages

Container => Page Header
```

**Widget Option Tab**

```
Select the newly created static block here
```

This is how you can show your custom messages at the top of the page.

[image]