# How to display custom notification or alert message on checkout pages?

Tags: magento2, global-messages, notification

Since the Covid mutation has arrived at our warehouse location, I'm looking for a way to use a text banner or something similar to inform people about possible unscheduled delays in shipping orders.

For this, I am looking for the easiest way to display custom alert messages on the checkout and checkout/cart pages. Do you have any good ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I decided to implement the notification banners with widgets and blocks.

How to do that is explained in [How To Add Custom Notices to Page Top in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176985/85880) by [@prince-partel](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/35758/prince-patel).